# Crash with using singletone in viewmodel

Tags: c#, xamarin, singleton

I have singletone for current user (in my app is doctor):

```
sealed class CurrentDataStorage
    {

        private static CurrentDataStorage dataStorage;

        private CurrentDataStorage()
        {

        }

        public static CurrentDataStorage DataStorage
        {
            get
            {
                if(dataStorage == null)
                {
                    dataStorage = new CurrentDataStorage();
                }
                return dataStorage;
            }
        }



        public Doctor CurrentDoctor { get
            {
                return CurrentDoctor;
            }
            set
            {
                if(CurrentDoctor != value)
                    CurrentDoctor = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

If i use this in viewmodel class i get crash my app. Maybe CurrentDoctor is null. I create some doctor in authorization page (it's stub for user create in backend):

```
public void OnAuthorization(object sender, EventArgs a)
        {
            CurrentDataStorage.DataStorage.CurrentDoctor = new Doctor("Иван", "Иванов", "Иванович", "house_md@gmail.com", "superdoctor321",
                        "Princeton Plainsboro", Model.Enums.Position.Researcher, Model.Enums.Category.Highest, Model.Enums.AcademicDegree.Doctor);
            Application.Current.MainPage = new ProfilePage();
        }
```

ProfilePage is masterdetail. I create this panel with binding:
[image]

Page code look like this:

```
public ProfilePageMaster()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.BindingContext = new ProfilePageMasterViewModel();
        }

        class ProfilePageMasterViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            Doctor doctor;

            public ProfilePageMasterViewModel()
            {
                doctor = CurrentDataStorage.DataStorage.CurrentDoctor;
            }

            public String FullName
            {
                get
                {
                    return doctor.FullName;
                }
            }

            #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
            {
                if (PropertyChanged == null)
                    return;

                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
            #endregion
        }
```

What i do wrong in using singletone?

UPD: this crash report (It doesn't tell me anything)

---

Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/kenzo/kenzo:6.0.1/MMB29M/8.11.8:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
pid: 10207, tid: 10207, name: hecksorexamarin  >>> com.pesiik.checksorexamarin <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x7fc77fad00
    x0   0000007fc77fad00  x1   000000559713ab50  x2   0000000000000290  x3   0000007f97712000
    x4   0000000000000000  x5   0000007f977126f0  x6   0000007fc77facf0  x7   0000007f79179f60
    x8   0000007f79179f70  x9   0000007f79179f60  x10  0000007f92cc1840  x11  0000007f92ccd630
    x12  0000007f92cb5748  x13  0000007f92ccaa70  x14  0000000000000003  x15  00000055977c7c58
    x16  0000007f8e457df8  x17  0000007f9767bc08  x18  6000000000000000  x19  0000000000000000
    x20  0000007f79072868  x21  0000007f79072868  x22  0000007f79117d90  x23  0000007f7907f2b0
    x24  0000000000000000  x25  0000000000000000  x26  0000007f79179f70  x27  0000000012cbe640
    x28  00000000729a2507  x29  0000007fc77fb020  x30  0000007f8e2344f8
    sp   0000007fc77fad00  pc   0000007f9767bd54  pstate 0000000020000000

backtrace:
    #00 pc 0000000000019d54  /system/lib64/libc.so (memcpy+332)
    #01 pc 00000000001094f4  /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-64bit-2.0.so

Comment: `If i use this in viewmodel class i get crash my app. Maybe CurrentDoctor is null` how do you know it crashes? If you see exception, then what is it? What does an error tells? What have you found during debugging session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your error is not related with singleton. Your property is killer - it accessing itself:

```
public Doctor CurrentDoctor 
 { 
    get
    {
       return CurrentDoctor;
    }
    set
    {
         if(CurrentDoctor != value)
            CurrentDoctor = value;
    }
 }
```

Use backing field instead

```
 private Doctor _currentDoctor
 public Doctor CurrentDoctor 
 { 
    get
    {
       return _currentDoctor;
    }
    set
    {
         if(_currentDoctor != value)
            _currentDoctor = value;
    }
 }
```